# How to quickly make the following action with the table?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, syntax, table

Consider the following two tables:

```
tab1 = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {10, 4}];
tab2 = RandomReal[{2, 3}, {10, 6}];
```

and "charges" each representing the corresponding two columns of the tables:

```
qvalsTab1 = (1 - RandomInteger[{0, 2}, Length[Transpose[tab1]]/2]);
qvalsTab2 = (1 - RandomInteger[{0, 2}, Length[Transpose[tab2]]/2]);
```

(i.e., `qvalsTab1[[1]]` represents the first two columns of `tab1`, and so on).

I would like to join distinct pairs of columns from both `tab1` and `tab2` with either opposite values of `qval` or if both of `qval` are zero, and then join the resulting tables. My dumb code looks as follows:

```
vals = {};
Do[vals = 
  Join[vals, 
   If[qvalsTab1[[i]]*qvalsTab2[[j]] == -1 || (qvalsTab1[[i]] == 0 && 
       qvalsTab2[[j]] == 0), 
    Join[tab1[[All, i*{1, 2}]], tab2[[All, j*{1, 2}]], 2], {}]], {i, 
  1, Length[qvalsTab1]}, {j, 1, Length[qvalsTab2], 1}]
Do[vals = 
  Join[vals, 
   If[qvalsTab1[[i]]*
       qvalsTab1[[j]] == -1 || (qvalsTab1[[i]] == 0 && 
        qvalsTab1[[j]] == 0) && i != j, 
    Join[tab1[[All, i*{1, 2}]], tab1[[All, j*{1, 2}]], 2], {}]], {i, 
  1, Length[qvalsTab1]}, {j, 1, Length[qvalsTab1]}]
Do[vals = 
  Join[vals, 
   If[qvalsTab2[[i]]*
       qvalsTab2[[j]] == -1 || (qvalsTab2[[i]] == 0 || 
        qvalsTab2[[j]] == 0) && i != j, 
    Join[tab2[[All, i*{1, 2}]], tab2[[All, j*{1, 2}]], 2], {}]], {i, 
  1, Length[qvalsTab2]}, {j, 1, Length[qvalsTab2]}]
```

May I please ask you whether there is a more elegant and faster solution (in reality, these tables are very long and the number of columns may be arbitrary) for this exercise?

Comment: So, the column-pairs aren't adjacent. You either select columns 1&2, or columns 2&4, or columns 3&6 and so forth. Is that correct?

Comment: In the first Do, you're collecting columns from both tab1 and tab2, in the second they all come from tab1, and in the third they all come from tab2. Correct? I hope my questions aren't presumptuous, but this code is very difficult to understand, and I keep losing track of what's happening. Would it actually be possible to describe your intent in pictures or clear words?

Comment: shouldn't  `(qvalsTab2[[i]] == 0|| qvalsTab
2[[j]] == 0)` in the last Do[...] be `(qvalsTab2[[i]] == 0 && qvalsTab2[[j]] == 0)`?

Comment: @lericr : yes, you are correct. Excuse me for the unclear code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tabs = {tab1, tab2};

qvals = {qvalsTab1, qvalsTab2};
```

**Note:** Assuming it is a typo, I replaced `(qvalsTab2[[i]] == 0|| qvalsTab 2[[j]] == 0)` in the last `Do[...]` in OP's code with `(qvalsTab2[[i]] == 0 && qvalsTab2[[j]] == 0)` to get `vals`.

**1.** A slightly shorter version of OP's code using another layer in `Do[...]`:

```
ClearAll[h, g, f]

h[qv_][k_, i_, j_] := MapThread[qv[[##]] &] @ {k, {i, j}}

g[t_][k_, i_, j_] := ## & @@ MapThread[t[[#, All, {1, 2} #2]] &] @ {k, {i, j}}

f = Module[{res = {}, l = Length /@ #2},
    Do[Module[{hv = h[#2][k, i, j], gv = Join[g[#][k, i, j], 2]},
      res = Join[res, If[Times @@ hv == -1 || (And @@ Thread[hv == 0] && 
              Or[Unequal @@ k, i != j]), gv, {}]]],
     {k, {{1, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}}},
     {i, 1, l[[First @ k]]},
     {j, 1, l[[Last @ k]]}]; 
    res] &;

 f[tabs, qvals] == vals
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**2.** An alternative approach:

```
ClearAll[selectIndices, joinColumns, combine]

selectIndices[vl_, neq_] := Select[Or[neq, Unequal @@ #] &&
     MatchQ[Sign@MapThread[vl[[##]] &]@{{1, 2}, #}, 
      {0, 0} | {1, -1} | {-1, 1}] &] @ Tuples[Range[Length /@ vl]]

joinColumns[t_] := Join[##,2]&@@MapThread[t[[#, All, {1, 2} #2]] &]@{{1, 2}, #} &

combine[tbs_, qvls_] := Apply[Join] @*
 Map[Join @@ Map[joinColumns@tbs[[#]]] @ selectIndices[qvls[[#]], Unequal@@#]&]


combine[tabs, qvals] @ {{1, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}} == vals
```

> ```
> True
> ```